# Configure webpack to compile partially scss file

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, sass

I am working with this Angular starter pack, works awesome, would recommend.

https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack

However in the project I would like to have one global `app.scss` which contains more `_partial.scss` files, like most sass projects, then have the components encapsulated scss files inside they're own directory, which also use the globals scss file.

However when I try to import a partial scss file into `app.scss` I get this error in my browsers console.

```
./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/style/app.scss
Module build failed: 
@import 'settings/_color';
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: settings/_color.
```

The files are definitely  in the right directory, I just can work out why webpack cannot compile them.

I'm pretty sure it is on this line: 121

```
 {
    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
    exclude: root('src', 'app'),
    loader: isTest ? 'null-loader' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']})
  }
```

can anyone help I can get the `app.scss` to compile successfully with the partial files?

Comment: Two things that I can think of: 1. Add the `.scss` extension to the import. Does that fix it? If not, 2. Try a relative path, eg `@import './settings/_color.scss';`

Comment: @Sidney I have tried both of these suggestions, however no lucj

Comment: Can you share your SCSS from both files?